# How can we create graph like below with lines and labels

Tags: d3.js, radial

I want to create 3 concentric arcs with line and labels with some HTML in the center.

One of the third arc overlaps the second arc. I want to add polylines with the labels to make it more descriptive.

below is the work done so far

---

[image]

Comment: Easy non-d3.js solution : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya Thank you for the reply. However I want to create the exact graph with lines and their labels.